# Unexpected Top Level Exception Google Play services

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I can't run the application because of an unexpected top level exception. I don't know if it is about my gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.warnyul.android.fast-video-view:fast-video-view:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'
}
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

UPDATE: Here is the error

```
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk430Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug


Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Usuario\SDK ANDROID STUDIO\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Usuario\ProjetoIgreja\ProjetoIgreja\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Usuario\ProjetoIgreja\ProjetoIgreja\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: We're going to need more info than that to help you. What exactly is the error?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, looks like Lumen's answer is correct. You need to enabled multidexing in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

You have exceeded the limit of 65,536 methods in dex file. This article will help you: [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html)